# What is AnotherVO, is it from POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I was looking for a way to read and edit docx file using java and found an answer with code from this link [Editing Word Document using Apache POI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981007/editing-word-document-using-apache-poi)

and there is a part of code from the answer

```
 public void wordDocProcessor(AnotherVO anotherData, ArrayList<String> list,
                                 String sourse, String destination) throws IOException,
```

So I wonder, what is this AnotherVO thing. I can't find it anywhere

Comment: `AnotherVO` seems to be simply a POJO having some getters (`getPointForBusiness`, `getE1url`, `getE2url`, `getE3url`) returning strings.

Comment: I think so too. But I am hoping there is something to it ;-;