# Java Regex : match whole word with word boundary

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to check whether a string contains a word as a whole, using Java. Below are some examples:

```
Text : "A quick brown fox"
Words:
"qui" - false
"quick" - true
"quick brown" - true
"ox" - false
"A" - true
```

Below is my code:

```
String pattern = "\\b(<word>)\\b";
String s = "ox";
String text = "A quick brown fox".toLowerCase();
System.out.println(Pattern.compile(pattern.replaceAll("<word>", s.toLowerCase())).matcher(text).find());
```

It works fine with strings like the one I mentioned in the above example. However, I get incorrect results if the input string has characters like `%`, `(` etc, e.g.:

```
Text : "c14, 50%; something (in) bracket"
Words:
"c14, 50%;" : false
"(in) bracket" : false
```

It has something to do with my `regex` pattern (or maybe I am doing the entire pattern matching wrongly). Could anyone suggest me a better approach.

Comment: Use `String pattern = "(?<!\\w)" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?!\\w)";`, `\b` is a context dependent pattern.

Comment: You'll need to escape regex special characters in your words list.  Otherwise, tell be interpreted by the engine.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks, it seems to cover most of the cases except `c14, 50%` and `c14, 50` where it should return `false`?

Comment: @DarshanMehta: Hm, it looks like you call those substrings "words" that are enclosed with whitespace? `String pattern = "(?<!\\S)" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?!\\S)";` should work then.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that worked like a charm! many thanks :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears you only want to match "words" enclosed with whitespace (or at the start/end of strings).

Use

```
String pattern = "(?<!\\S)" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?!\\S)";
```

The `(?<!\S)` negative lookbehind will fail all matches that are immediately preceded with a char other than a whitespace and `(?!\s)` is a negative lookahead that will fail all matches that are immediately followed with a char other than whitespace. `Pattern.quote()` is necessary to escape special chars that need to be treated as literal  chars in the regex pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Try escape the special characters with the backslash. They can have other meanings in a pattern.

small correction: Probably you even need two backslash, since the backslash itself is a special character in a String.