# Making a string inside a sentence bold - Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

How do I make a string bold while it's inside a sentence?

I've just started using Apache POI like 4 hours ago and wanted to:

1. Locate different strings inside a Word-Document (.docx/XWPF)
2. Replace the strings with the value of the map
3. Make the value appear bold, if the string has a special flag.

I tried to first approach this by iterating over the paragraph (not the Runs), but it didn't work. I've got my current solution from this post right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49765239/16028444).

Everything is fine with the first two steps, now I want to make every value that contains a special flag (like `${key:bold}` or `${score:bold}`) bold. I've tried to create a new `XWPFRun` that writes the bold string, it just won't work with the code underneath...

`ParagraphFieldReplacer.java` (Currently working for step 1 and 2)

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFParagraph;
import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun;

public final class ParagraphFieldReplacer {
    
    public static void replace(final Student student, final XWPFDocument document, final Map<String, FormatObject> fields) {
        final List<XWPFParagraph> paragraphs = document.getParagraphs();
        for (final XWPFParagraph paragraph : paragraphs)
            replaceParagraph(student, paragraph, fields);
    }
    
    private static void replaceParagraph(final Student student, final XWPFParagraph paragraph, final Map<String, FormatObject> fields) throws POIXMLException {
        List<XWPFRun> runs;
        String paragraphtext;
        String runsText;
        XWPFRun nextRun;
        String target;
        XWPFRun run;
        for (final String key : fields.keySet()) {
            paragraphtext = paragraph.getText();
            if (!(paragraphtext.contains("${")))
                return;
            target = "${" + key + "}";
            if (!(paragraphtext.contains(target)))
                continue;
            runs = paragraph.getRuns();
            for (int i = 0; i < runs.size(); i++) {
                run = runs.get(i);
                runsText = run.getText(0);
                if (runsText.contains("${") || (runsText.contains("$") && runs.get(i + 1).getText(0).substring(0, 1).equals("{"))) {
                    while (!(openTagCountIsEqualCloseTagCount(runsText))) {
                        nextRun = runs.get(i + 1);
                        runsText = runsText + nextRun.getText(0);
                        paragraph.removeRun(i + 1);
                    }
                    if (!(runsText.contains(target)))
                        run.setText(runsText, 0);
                    else {
                        final FormatObject format = fields.get(key);
                        final String handle = format.handle(student);
                        run.setText(runsText.replace(target, handle), 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private static boolean openTagCountIsEqualCloseTagCount(final String runText) {
        final int openTagCount = (runText.split("\\$\\{", -1).length - 1);
        final int closeTagCount = (runText.split("}", -1).length - 1);
        return (openTagCount == closeTagCount);
    }
    
}
```

`FormatObject.java`

```java
public final class FormatObject {
    
    private boolean bold;
    private FormatHandler<Student, String> handler;
    
    public FormatObject(final FormatHandler<Student, String> handler, final boolean bold) {
        this.handler= handler;
        this.bold = bold;
    }
    
    public boolean isBold() {
        return bold;
    }
    
    public String handle(final ZertifikationsStudent student) {
        return handler.handle(student);
    }
    
}
```

`FormatHandler.java`

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface FormatHandler<P, R> {
    
    public R handle(P p);
    
}
```

Thanks for reading/helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working the other day!

The best way to make it bold is to make the format-indicator bold in the document itself.

The other way is to create a new `XWPFRun` and set it to `bold`. The text should be the value of the key. After that, you can just add all the fixed `XWPFRun`s into an `ArrayList` and re-insert them, after removing every run in the selected paragraph. You can then just remove the old-normal `XWPFRun` that contains the format-indicator.