# How to change content inside table/Nested table in docx file using apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I am using apache POI to change the styling of data in docx  file. I am able to change the text styles on normal paragraphs but when it comes to the content that is present in table, it does not change.

```
 public static void changeStyle(XWPFParagraph paragraph, Map<String, String> translation_keyDataMap,JSONObject style) 
  {
     for (int runNumber = 0; runNumber < paragraph.getRuns().size(); runNumber++) 
       {
           XWPFRun run = paragraph.getRuns().get(runNumber);
            String runText= run.getText(0);

            if(runText!=null)
            {
                runText=runText.replace(" "," ");
                run.setColor(style.getString("color"));
                run.setFontFamily(style.getString("font"));

            }

        }

    }
```

[image: Screenshot of the output docx file where table content has not changed to RED]

Comment: You'll need to find all the runs that between them contain your text - Word almost never merges runs back together when formatting no longer differs, so you need to cope with this Word "feature"

Comment: the thing is, even the words are split in different runs, so finding the word in the run won't work, also if i apply loop to search any word then it will change font of that particular word wherever it finds it.

Comment: @Gagravarr  i have modifyed the question with few more details, need help here